# GWT Timer fires immediately, when running gwt-test-utils unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, gwt, junit, timer

I wrote an unit test using the gwt-test-utils framework, as described [here](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-test-utils/wiki/SimpleUnitTest).
The tested class internally uses a `com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer` (not the Java default Timer).

Only when tested, though, the Timer instance doesn't behave correctly, as it fires as soon as it is scheduled.

When I run this test

```
public class TimerTest extends GwtTest {
  @Override
  public String getModuleName() {
    return "com.whatevs";
  }

  @Test
  public void testTimer() {
    final int[] counter = { 0 };

    com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer t = new Timer() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Log.info("firing timer");
        counter[0]++; // just increase the counter
      }
    };

    Log.info("scheduling timer");
    t.schedule(1000000); // this should return immediately
    Log.info("scheduling returns");
    assertEquals(0, counter[0]); // the counter shouldn't yet be incremented
  }
}
```

I get a failure

```
testTimer(com.whatevs.TimerTest): expected:<0> but was:<1>
```

And the debug output

```
22:37:44,075  INFO gwt-log:81 - scheduling timer
22:37:44,075  INFO gwt-log:81 - firing timer
22:37:44,075  INFO gwt-log:81 - scheduling returns
```

Please note that the test is run as a JUnit test, without being compiled to JavaScript first.

Am I doing something wrong, or did I just hit a bug?
Is there any other way to test such classes?

**Update**:

I just found out that if in the above example i call scheduleRepeating, or I reschedule the timer using schedule inside the run method, the timer fires exactly 5 times before returning control to the caller.

Something weird is going on, I just opened [a bug report](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-test-utils/issues/detail?id=157) on gwt-test-utils.

Comment: which looks like it's been solved